# Pasting a PNG on a image using homography in openCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, homography

I tried to paste a png image on another image(jpg) using homography in openCV by using [this example.](https://www.learnopencv.com/homography-examples-using-opencv-python-c/)  And jpg format is working with this but when I try to do with png the white area shows. And I also tried with using adding -1 and `cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED` in the imread which doesn't change the image but the code doesn't run after that. Please suggest me a way to paste a png. Would be a great help. The code is this and the images will follow.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from utils import mouse_handler
from utils import get_four_points
import sys


if __name__ == '__main__' :

    # Read source image.
    im_src = cv2.imread('first-image.jpg');
    size = im_src.shape

    # Create a vector of source points.
    pts_src = np.array(
                       [
                        [0,0],
                        [size[1] - 1, 0],
                        [size[1] - 1, size[0] -1],
                        [0, size[0] - 1 ]
                        ],dtype=float
                       );


    # Read destination image
    im_dst = cv2.imread('times-square.jpg');

    # Get four corners of the billboard
    print 'Click on four corners of a billboard and then press ENTER'
    pts_dst = get_four_points(im_dst)

    # Calculate Homography between source and destination points
    h, status = cv2.findHomography(pts_src, pts_dst);

    # Warp source image
    im_temp = cv2.warpPerspective(im_src, h, (im_dst.shape[1],im_dst.shape[0]))

    # Black out polygonal area in destination image.
    cv2.fillConvexPoly(im_dst, pts_dst.astype(int), 0, 16);

    # Add warped source image to destination image.
    im_dst = im_dst + im_temp;

    # Display image.
    cv2.imshow("Image", im_dst);
    cv2.waitKey(0);
```

**IMAGES :**
https://github.com/spmallick/learnopencv/blob/master/Homography/first-image.jpg
https://github.com/spmallick/learnopencv/blob/master/Homography/times-square.jpg

**UTILS CLASS**
https://github.com/spmallick/learnopencv/blob/master/Homography/utils.py

It would be great if you can provide me an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probem is solved in [this link](https://www.learnopencv.com/alpha-blending-using-opencv-cpp-python/). PNG formats have an extra channel called 'alpha' for transparency.